# Azure Databricks - Long running processes

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-workflows

All,

I'm in the process of learning Databricks. If there is a runaway process that has been running a Job Cluster, I would like to get notified/alerted and if possible event terminated. In SQLServer, this is normally done with the help of Query Governor.

IS there something comparable in **Azure Databricks** that I put to use?

Thanks,
grajee

Answer (score 0):

[Databricks jobs (or new name - workflows) support sending the email alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-engineering/jobs/jobs#--alerts) on jobs start and/or termination (successful or errors only) - just use UI or API to configure these notifications.  Also you can configure such notifications on the level of individual tasks inside the workflow/job

Answer (score 0):

You can add one or more email addresses to notify when runs of this job begin, complete, or fail:

1. Click **Edit alerts**.
2. Click **Add**.
3. Enter the email address to notify and click the check box for each alert type to send to that address.
4. To enter another email address for notification, click **Add**.
5. If you do not want to receive alerts for skipped job runs, click the check box.
6. Click **Confirm**.

[image]